# How do I import a variable to file where I keep my functions in python?

Tags: python

I have just begun learning python, and there's an error I've been trying to find my way around for a long time. For one of my programs, its skeleton code looks something like this:

```
import importtest

x = input("Number")

importtest.greeting()

importtest.bye()
```

And I have another file named importtest where I keep the functions. However, the functions require x, which I'm not sure how to import from my main file to importtest. If I do it like this:

```
from mainfiletest import *

def greeting():

  print("Hello, bob")

def bye():

  print("Bye, bob" + number)
```

I will get the error where it tells me there is a circular import. How do I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: If the functions require `x`, then *pass it to them as a parameter*.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the variable into the function as a parameter like this:

```
def my_function(num):
    print("My number: " + repr(num))
x = input("Number")
my_function(x)
```